# What does "position" mean when doing a Github card move http get request?

Tags: api, github, postman

I am trying to move a Github project card. But I don't quite understand what "position" mean in the docs

"position   string  body Required. The position of the card in a column"
https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/projects#move-a-project-card

I am trying to do a post request with Postman. But I keep getting a message "problems parsing JSON"
And I entered authorization and accept headers already(I have tested it with different URL before and those work fine)

[image: project view]

Answer (score 1):

I'm a writer on GitHub's documentation team. A colleague pointed me to this post and I wanted to share that I've updated [Move a project card](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/projects#move-a-project-card) (and [Move a project column](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/projects#move-a-project-column)) to describe what we're expecting as the `position` parameter.

When moving a card, you can provide one of "top", "bottom", or if you wish to place the card after another, "after:<card_id>" (replacing <card_id> with the ID of the card).